# Structure member alignment of 1 byte at rust compilation (rustflags)

Tags: visual-c++, rust, cl

Hello I'm trying to do some Cobol with rust x86/msvc (with Microfocus RM Cobol on Windows 10) and that works partially because:

In the Cobol documentation I have to pass :

```
-Zp1
```

> specifies structure member alignment of 1 byte

to cl.exe (Microsoft Visual C++ compiler)

I didn't pass this argument because I have this error:

```
..\winnt.h(2487): error C2118: indice négatif
```

And without that argument I can only work with maximum 255 integer, after that the program is buggy (but it compiles).

Is it possible to specify a rustflag to compile with alignement of 1 byte ?

I find something like that for Struct

```
#[repr(align(64))]
struct S(u8);
```

But nothing for

```
[build]
rustflags = []
```

Edit: It works without bug and compile with Zp1 (rust) with visual c++ 2010 runtime (as mentioned in the RMCobol batch file)

Comment: There is no global flag for alignment, the equivalent would be `#[repr(packed)]` on the struct. See the entry for it in the [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprpacked).